# Decrypt audio file using pgp private key | Python

Tags: python, encryption, pgp

I am trying to decrypt audio file using PGP private key and passphrase but getting following error. I am not sure were to add "User ID"

```
prv_key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file(str(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE))
PASSPHRASE  = "PASSPHRASE1124124"
print(" is key protected " ,prv_key.is_protected)  
with prv_key.unlock(PASSPHRASE):
   print("is key unlocked ",prv_key.is_unlocked) 
   decrpted_file = prv_key.decrypt("encryptedfilename")
```

errro: raise PGPError("Key is not complete - please add a User ID!")
pgpy.errors.PGPError: Key is not complete - please add a User ID!

Answer (score 0):

According to [pgpy documentation](https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), you could try:

```py
uid = pgpy.PGPUID.new('your id', comment='your comment', email='your email')
```

then

```py
prv_key.add_uid(uid, [+options])
```